# How to design view similar to settings app in Ipad?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am working on a project i which i want to design the view similar to that of settings app in Ipad. Before this i implemented the view by using Tabbed Page.Please give me any hint to design this kind of layout.I will be posting in this if i get any solutions for this.Please Help me if solution is available.Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: Please provide the code of your current approach or the tools you are willing to use. Read [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if needed

Comment: Your questions is not clear. "i want to design the view similar to that of settings app in Ipad" You mean the view Split in two or you mean the right part with the List and the Switches ?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for a SwitchCell implementation. Take a look at this:  https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.SwitchCell/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a grid with two columns.

**The first column**

Contain a **ListView** with a **Tap Event**. When an element is tapped you shoud load or set view in second grid visible.

**The Second column**

You can have some **ContentView** related to each of your **ListView** items

**Links**

1. [ListView](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/)
2. [Grid](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid/)
3. [ContentView](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ContentView/)