# Master Detail Page in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to know, is it possible to display master page always,means even after clicking something in master page it should navigate to other page but master page should be visible always.

Comment: like this ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45711651/how-to-design-view-similar-to-settings-app-in-ipad

Comment: Yes exactly@Cole Xia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var page = new MasterDetailPage();
page.MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.Split;
```

Comment: Thank you @Will Decker,This is what iam looking for